# Getting initial_filter to work with subpanel's Select button

Tags: sugarcrm, suitecrm

In Suitecrm have a subpanel and when clicking 'Select' I want it to show only a specific set of records.

[image]

I have a subpanel definition file that looks like this and tried all possible variations in the section "initial_filter" but when the pop-up comes up it shows all of the records

```
$layout_defs["un_inventory"]["subpanel_setup"]['un_inventory_leads_1'] = array (
  'order' => 0,
  'module' => 'Leads',
  'subpanel_name' => 'default',
  'sort_order' => 'asc',
  'sort_by' => 'id',
  'title_key' => 'LBL_UN_INVENTORY_LEADS_1_FROM_LEADS_TITLE',
  //'get_subpanel_data' => 'un_inventory_leads_1',

    'get_subpanel_data' => 'function:get_parent_leads',
    'function_parameters' =>
        array('import_function_file' => 'custom/modules/Leads/func/get_parent_leads_file.php',),

  'top_buttons' => 
  array (
    0 => 
    array (
      'widget_class' => 'SubPanelTopButtonQuickCreate',
    ),
    1 =>
    array (
      //'widget_class' => 'SubPanelTopSelectButton',
      'widget_class' => 'SubPanelTopSelectButtonParentProjectLeads',
      'mode' => 'MultiSelect',
      // 'initial_filter_fields' => "&first_name_advanced=hello",
      // 'initial_filter' => array('parent_project_id_c_advanced' => array('83b30b20-83a6-8099-b3b9-5d4a491888e6')),
      // 'initial_filter' => array('parent_project_id_c_advanced' => '83b30b20-83a6-8099-b3b9-5d4a491888e6'),
      // 'initial_filter' => array('account_type_advanced' => array('Student')),
      // 'initial_filter' => '&parent_project_id_c=83b30b20-83a6-8099-b3b9-5d4a491888e6',

    ),
  ),
);
```

There are many example of how this is done for 'relate' fields in editview, but not so much for subpanel's such as above, I'm pretty sure many would find this valuable.

Solution would probably be applicable to sugarcrm CE also

Comment: Sugar and SuiteCRM are very different in this aspect, but maybe I can still help you out. In Sugar relate fields natively support intial_filter, however subpanels do not. For it to work we had to specify a custom panel controller if I remember correctly - basing it on a stock custom one. Prospectslists I believe? Maybe you can pull off something similar by going on initial_filter panel hunt in your SuiteCRM using this bash command: `grep -RIl initial_filter | grep -i panel`

Comment: PS: And yes, I'm referring to the select action, not the panel contents. Sorry for being so unspecific.

Comment: Hi there Jay, thank you! I'll give this a try

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution is to override the default TopButtonSelect class and hardcode the $initial_filter variable.

So if we hardcode the value like so

```
    $initial_filter.='&parent_project_id_c_advanced='.urlencode("83b30b20-83a6-8099-b3b9-5d4a491888e6");
```

It will only show records which have the parent_project_id_c field with the value 83b30b20-83a6-8099-b3b9-5d4a491888e6

Hope this helps

Source: http://qc-digital.com/filter-values-shown-when-we-click-on-select-button-inside-a-subpanel/

Answer (score 2):

The above soluton proposed by Robert Sinclair does work, but it creates a dedicated-use situation.  If instead you wanted to create a solution that will let you use the changes to have a functional initial_filter for any subpanel, make the following edits.

Thank you to Robert Sinclair and qc-digital.com for not only showing how to make his solution work but also for explaining why the expected method does not work, enabling the edits below to fix the SugarWidget and have it behave as expected.

Two fixes in this post:

a) Have the initial_filter_fields array be checked against the target
module not the host module
b) have the key=>value arrangement in the
layoutdefs work like it does in other situations

Two steps to make this fix work:

1. Create a custom SugarWidget
2. Tell the subpanel to use the custom SugarWidget and add the initial_filter_fields array to the TopSelectButton definition

You can then use the custom SugarWidget in any other subpanel and the initial_filter_field will work

1. Create the custom SugarWidget

   ```
    mkdir -p custom/include/generic/SugarWidgets/

    cp -a include/generic/SugarWidgets/SugarWidgetSubPanelTopSelectButton.php custom/include/generic/SugarWidget/SugarWidgetSubPanelTopSelectButtonWithFilter.php

    nano custom/include/generic/SugarWidgets/SugarWidgetSubPanelTopSelectButtonWithFilter.php
   ```

   Change

   ```
    class SugarWidgetSubPanelTopSelectButton extends SugarWidgetSubPanelTopButton
   ```

   To

   ```
    class SugarWidgetSubPanelTopSelectButtonWithFilter extends SugarWidgetSubPanelTopButton
   ```

   Change

   ```
        if (isset($widget_data['initial_filter_fields'])) {
            if (is_array($widget_data['initial_filter_fields'])) {
                foreach ($widget_data['initial_filter_fields'] as $value=>$alias) {
                    if (isset($focus->$value) and !empty($focus->$value)) {
                        $initial_filter.="&".$alias . '='.urlencode($value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
   ```

   To

   ```
        /*
         * Edited Below to use the target module not the host module
         * and to use the normal key=>value arrangement
        if (isset($widget_data['initial_filter_fields'])) {
            if (is_array($widget_data['initial_filter_fields'])) {
                foreach ($widget_data['initial_filter_fields'] as $value=>$alias) {
                    if (isset($focus->$value) and !empty($focus->$value)) {
                        $initial_filter.="&".$alias . '='.urlencode($value);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        */
        if (isset($widget_data['initial_filter_fields'])) {
            if (is_array($widget_data['initial_filter_fields'])) {
                foreach ($widget_data['initial_filter_fields'] as $alias=>$value) {
                    $initial_filter.="&".$alias . '='.urlencode($value);
                }
            }
        }
   ```
2. Tell the subpanel to use the custom SugarWidget (in my case, editing the Events module (FP_events) subpanel I created pointing to Accounts ... edit to suit your situation)

   nano custom/Extension/modules/FP_events/Ext/Layoutdefs/fp_events_accounts_1_FP_events.php

   Change

   ```
    array (
      'widget_class' => 'SubPanelTopSelectButton',
      'mode' => 'MultiSelect',
    ),
   ```

   To

   ```
    array (
      'widget_class' => 'SubPanelTopSelectButtonWithFilter',
      'mode' => 'MultiSelect',
      'initial_filter_fields' => array(
        'account_type_advanced' => 'Venue',
      ),
    ),
   ```

You will now be able to use the initial_filter_fields functionality in any subpanel by specifying the custom SugarWidget and including the initial_filter_fields array definition in the TopSelectButton definition.